# Predicting whether a customer will deposit in the next 30 days

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am trying to figure out what type of a machine learning model to build for the following case:

I want to be able to predict whether a customer will deposit in the next 30 days, using past data:

```py
# Data 
import pandas as pd
client_id = [1 , 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
deposit_amount = [10, 20, 30, 15, 45, 55]
deposit_date = ["2022-01-05", "2022-01-06", "2022-01-07", "2022-01-05", "2022-01-06", "2022-01-06"]
dat = pd.DataFrame([client_id, deposit_amount, deposit_date]).T
dat.columns = ["client_id", "deposit_amount", "deposit_date"]
dat


# Use ML algorithm
---


# Output of the ML Algorithm
model_prediction = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3],[0, 1, 0]]).T
model_prediction.columns = ["client_id", "target"]
```

As you can see there are multiple rows for a customer for each time when they deposit. Which machine learning algorithm do you suggest? Since I am trying to predict something time related, is there any model which can deal with time-based data and outputs a binary column?

Answer (score 1):

You can use whatever you want as classification algorithm (SVC, RandomForest, LogisticRegression, etc). The most important thing is to prepare your data correctly.

For example, the `date` variable is not useful as such but the time delta before two deposits is interesting for you:

```
dat['deposit_date'] = pd.to_datetime(dat['deposit_date'])
dat['deposit_date'] = dat.groupby('client_id')['deposit_date'].diff().dt.days.fillna(0)
```

Once you have prepared your data, it is important to normalize/standardize them to avoid giving importance to certain variables with large numbers.

You can use several algorithms and compare them. You can also try different hyper settings for each model (watch out for overfitting).

The second most important thing is choosing your metric to evaluate your model. As you have classification problem (and more specifically binary classification), you need to use metrics like f1-score, precision, recall.

As you can see, the choice of the algorithm is not very important compared to your analysis of the problem :-)

Comment: For me it sounds like a model with some "memory" would be more suitable (GRU / LSTM), a RNN in general and it's not a classification problem imho. The OP needs the current/future data (or a series of data points) based on previous values.

Comment: @Corralien Would you recommend there is one row for each client or multiple rows per client?

Comment: @Gameplay. I'm agree with you but before using some RNN, it would be interesting to study simple model to check the accuracy.

Comment: @Gameplay is there a machine learning model you recommend other than RNNs, I like the idea but I am not yet familiar with deep learning concepts

Comment: In fact, you have to keep only one row per user. So you have to create another columns: number of deposit last 1year, 6months, 3months, 1month, 15days.